# Ошибка триггера SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_todo;


CREATE TRIGGER update_todo AFTER DELETE ON user_todo_send FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE todo SET status = 1 WHERE id = OLD.id_todo; 
END;


DELETE FROM user_todo_send WHERE id_todo IN
(   
  SELECT something.id_todo FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        uts.id_todo AS id_todo 
    FROM 
        user_todo_send uts INNER JOIN 
        todo ON todo.id = uts.id_todo 
    WHERE 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, todo.time_created, NOW()) > uts.time
  ) AS something
)
```

Запрос удаления и триггер для него, в результате получаю ошибку

> General error: 1442 Can't update table `'todo'` in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger. The SQL statement executed was: 
>   `DELETE FROM user_todo_send`

Comment: Дублировать вопросы не стоит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Триггер пытается изменить таблицу `todo`, которая участвует в запросе `DELETE FROM`. В MySQL не позволяется выполнять такие операции во избежание дедлоков.

Comment: Я понял но как решить эту проблему? мне необходимо обращаться к todo иначе я не смогу вычислить поля для удаления

Comment: Нужно менять логику работы с таблицами. Первое, что в голову пришло: создайте, например, временную таблицу, отберите туда нужные `id_todo`. А потом двумя запросами удалите из `user_todo_send` и обновите `todo`.

Comment: спасибо за совет я уже думал так поступить но вопрос оптимизации очень важен. Поэтому я избавился от использования todo при вычислении записей для удаления и все заработало